How could I have VScode on Windows 10 with the default terminal changed to WSL2 Ubuntu-24.04 like a native linux distro?
I'm trying to have inside VScode for Windows 10 (Microsoft Windows [versão 10.0.19045.4474]) options to change the terminal from default to another one such WSL2 Ubuntu 24.04.
I have installed powershell 7.4.2 MSI version:

Powershell 7.4.2
Checked with:
$PSVersionTable 

Get the following output:

I have checked WSL version:
wsl -l -v


Checked the default distro (padrão=standard - PT-BR - US):
wsl --list


I have saw the default one with the following command:
wsl -l -v


Set to default Ubuntu 24.04 and listed:

wsl --setdefault DISTRO-NAME

wsl --setdefault Ubuntu 24.04

wsl -l -v

Checked if changed to Ubuntu 24.04 and worked fine!

Have done a list again:
wsl --list


Now I figure about a recommendation to install a VScode extension:

Have done the install:

I have discovered the down arrow in the output section and you can choose to Ubuntu 24.04 (WSL):

Have done some bash commands:

The problem I facing is that show Windows directories.

In the Windows explorer you can see linux folders and files:

Would like to open a terminal similar this image bellow inside VScode terminal like a native distro (the same way you that you can see in the image above of windows explorer):


It looks like you've asked at least 5 different questions. Can you please focus on a single question here? Use the EDIT button to focus your question.

Point for me the 5 questions so I can fix. I tried to explain in a detailed way. What I want is open a terminal in VScode and see the same way WS2 Ubuntu 24.04. So open like a native distro, without Windows directories.
@music2myear
